# Change Sub Form Based On Selected Option in C# WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, forms

I apologize for the poor title, I don't know how else to explain it.

I have an interface like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0AMl.png) (sorry can't post an image directly as I'm new).

And I want to have the right side display controls based on the tree selection on the left. What's the easiest way to do this in a WPF project? Is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would use the MVVM design pattern to do this, but if you're looking for a simple and easy way to get this working, you could try this... Create UserControls to be the different subforms, and throw them into a frame.  You could use a grid as well, but a frame allows you to use navigation (forward, back) if you need it.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

    <!--TreeView Code Here-->
    <TreeView x:Name="treeView" SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Devices" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Device 1" Tag="UserControl1.xaml"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Device 2" Tag="UserControl2.xaml"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Device 3" Tag="UserControl3.xaml"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Users" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Add" Tag="UserControl4.xaml"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Edit/Delete" Tag="UserControl5.xaml"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>

    <!--Frame to hold your subform (UserControl)-->
    <Frame x:Name="SubForm" Grid.Column="2" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
</Grid>
```

CodeBehind:

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)treeView.SelectedItem;
    SubForm.Source = new Uri(item.Tag.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. This points me in the right direction and gives me a couple options. I'm going to look into the MVVM design patter as well. - Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should use MDI form. Add your treeview controller in it. In treeview event handlers you can show sub form based on your selected item. Make sure to set "MdiParent" property of subform to MDI form.